# pyspark continuous invocation of UDF when using between method filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I'm experiencing a UDF being invoked continuously when I call the `filter` method on a `DataFrame` and use the `between` method as a condition.

UDF

```
@udf(returnType=FloatType())
def test_udf(value):
    calc = value * 2.00
    return calc
```

Adding a new column to my DF:

```
df.withColumn("value_of_cash", test_udf(lit(2)))
```

Now filtering with `between`:

```
df = df.filter(
    df.value_of_cash.between(0, df.spending_wise)
)
```

There isn't any error message, but I can see from logs that the UDF function gets invoked multiple times when using the between method call.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does **lazy evaluation**. That means it will listen to you and absolutely do nothing and continue to do until you ask for final answer.

In your example the `between` clause can only be executed when your column `value_of_cash` is computed. To compute `value_of_cash` it needs to run the UDF as many times equal to number of rows in your data. For spark, UDFs are black box and therefore it stupidly computes it for every row.

Comment: Is the work around to first cache the resulting dataframe that gets created with calling the withColumn API before filtering?

Comment: Try this : `df.withColumn("value_of_cash", test_udf(lit(2))).cache().count()`